# Get UserName within Login to check if it's Administrator Role

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, roles, user-roles

I have a little problem.
I'd like to check if the user is in role admin after clicking login.
I have one problem left when doing it with

```
if(User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
```

User == null and i can't figure out another way to do it.

I tried several things but nothing actually works.

It should be withing this

```
 switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                //check if user is admin
                if (Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains("Administrator"))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "MIS");
                }
                else
                    return View();
```

Comment: Have you checked what the value is of the user that's being passed in?

Comment: when i do `User.IsInRole("Admin")` User = null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're no longer getting access to the `Http Context User` object so here is a workaround

```
 switch (result)
           {
               case SignInStatus.Success:
                   //check if user is admin
                   var adminRole = context.Roles.Where(r => r.Name == "Administrator").FirstOrDefault();
                   var user = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == model.Username).FirstOrDefault();
                   if(user.Roles.Where(r => r.RoleId == adminRole.Id).Count() > 0)
                   {
                       return RedirectToAction("Index", "MIS");
                   }
                   else
                       return View();
```